# Entity association to FOS User

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create association from my entity 'Entry' to entity FosUserUser.
I created table Entry in database and relation to fos_user_user and then doctrine generated entities by:
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeDemoBundle annotation
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeDemoBundle

Generated entity in shortcut:

```
/**
 * Entries
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="entry", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="user_id", columns={"user_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entry {
 .............

 /**
 * @var \FosUserUser
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FosUserUser")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\FosUseUser $user
 */
public function setUser(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\FosUseUser $user = null)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
}
}
```

Doctrine generated entity with setUser(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Entry $user = null) and i changed it to setUser(\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\FosUseUser $user = null).

Now Im trying to create object Entry
 public function addEntryAction() {

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:FosUserUser')->find($this->getUser()->getId());

$new_entry = new Entry;
$new_entry->setEntry('test');
$new_entry->setUser($user);

$em->persist($new_entry);
$em->flush();
```

End the problem is that Symfony doesnt match my entities and respond error
**Found entity of type Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\FosUserUser on association Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Entry#user, but expecting Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Entry**

Is it association created corectly or where is the problem?

Comment: Somewhere in the code you did not copy here, there's a method who's variable declaration you did not change from Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Entry to Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\FosUserUser .

Comment: is `\Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\FosUseUser` class correct? You're talking about some `FosUserUser` class but type hinting as `FosUseUser` class in `setUser` method..

Comment: is it not enought to declare in class Entry?

 /**
 * @var \FosUserUser
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FosUserUser")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;

Comment: my Entry Entity
http://pastebin.com/c1h3jNPA

Comment: @xurshid29
FosUserUser class http://pastebin.com/5JWRbSQE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i resolved it. 
Is another doctrine config file src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Entry.orm.xml with relation:

```
<many-to-one field="user" target-entity="Entry"> //should be target-entity="FosUserUser"
  <join-columns>
    <join-column name="user_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
  </join-columns>
</many-to-one>
```